# check if image is valid before uploading-- mootools

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

I'm using mootools request to push image data to a server to import images. My question is how to determine if an image path is valid before completing the request?

Here's what I have now--

http://jsfiddle.net/sTbFb/1/

```
function doUpload(){
  var remoteFile = document.id('uploadRemote').get('value');
  var imageRequest = new Request({
      url:'index.php', 
      method: 'post',
      data: 'path='+remoteFile,
      onRequest: function() {
        console.log(remoteFile);
        var myimage = Asset.image(remoteFile,
          {
            //onError: imageRequest.cancel() // <-- this doesn't work either
            onError: this.cancel()
          }
        );
      },
      onSuccess: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    }).send();
}

document.id('submit').addEvent('click', function(){
    doUpload();
});
```

I'm trying to use Asset.image to test if a path is truly an image-- then if it's not, to cancel the request. However, it's not working out.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the path to the selected file from an `<input type="file" />`.  So, you won't be able to load it before you upload it. The best you can do is to check the file extension.

---

**Edit:** Perhaps the problem is with this line:

```
onError: this.cancel()
```

It should be:

```
onError: function () {
    imageRequest.cancel();
}
```

Comment: it's not a file upload-- it's just a path. The idea is that people can add a remote link to a hosted image on their server (hotlink if you like) and after verifying that it's an image and it's accessible then it'll be inserted into an image table.

Comment: from teh fiddle-- <input type="text" id="uploadRemote" value="">

Comment: @julio - `onError` expects a function, but you are assigning it the result of a function call.  See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @gilly3-- thanks! However, using the function still gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'cancel' of undefined`.

Comment: @julio you can make a head request to the remote image from php or other server side language and check its mime type. Another approach would be to read the first x bytes of the file and check if it's an image or not. jpeg, gif, png images have a distinct header - this is the most secure way to do it

Comment: @vlad-- thanks, I was planning on doing that on the action page, but thought it might be nice to kick out non-images early using JS prior to calling the loader page.

Comment: @julio - works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/sTbFb/2/.  Check to make sure you do not have a typo in `imageRequest`, since the error message indicates it is undefined.  Is the `imageRequest` variable in the same scope as the `onError` handler?